# why __name__ is equal to __main__?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I understand that `__main__` is the name of `__main__.py`, which in this case is `test_employee`. But what I don't understand is the unittest module and the class that I want to test are being imported.
Then why `__name__` is still same as `__main__`? As I understood, `__name__` represents the modules being imported.

*test_employee.py*

```
import unittest

from employee import Employee

class TestEmployee(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.employee1 = Employee('June', 'July')
        self.employee2 = Employee('Jane', 'Marshal')
    
    def test_give_default_raise(self):
        self.assertEqual(5000, self.employee1.annual_salary)

    def test_give_custom_raise(self):
        self.employee2.give_raise(1000)
        self.assertEqual(6000, self.employee2.annual_salary)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: The module that is originally executed receives the name `__main__`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html

Answer (score 3):

`__main__` is a very particular function of python. It has mainly two interests:

- `if __name__ == '__main__'` condition
- `__main__.py` file for a module (which is not the purpose hier)

When importing a module, the `__name__` attribute of this module is set to the name of the module (i.e. the file name without the .py extension).

```py
>>> import my_module
>>> my_module.__name__
'my_module'

>>> import my_module.submodule
>>> my_module.submodule.__name__
'my_module.submodule'
```

However, if the attribute is called from the main runtime environment (which is the main use case), then the variable will always contain the value `'__main__'`.
The main purpose of this is to test whether the main script is called from the main runtime environment or not.
This is usefull to differentiate the case where the module is called directly (for instance from command line) and the one where it is loaded from another module (to launch an argparse, for example...)

*Nevertheless, it is recommended to put as little code as possible under the condition `if __name__ == '__main__'` to avoid errors.*

It is recommended to do as follows:

```py
# echo.py

import shlex
import sys

def echo(phrase: str) -> None:
   """A dummy wrapper around print."""
   # for demonstration purposes, you can imagine that there is some
   # valuable and reusable logic inside this function
   print(phrase)

def main() -> int:
    """Echo the input arguments to standard output"""
    phrase = shlex.join(sys.argv)
    echo(phrase)
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Pardon me, you mean that `__name__ ` is the name of the file without the `.py` extension? Like if my file name is `mycode.py` the __name__ here is mycode, and the condition needs `main` so how the code will run? I understood the first part, but facing some issue understanding the second part, sorry.

Comment: Oh yeah, I got your point but if the attribute is called not from the environment, so it depends on the Python File Name, right ?

Comment: Yes, if you are in e the "main file" (the one you call from command-line), `__name__` is equals to `"__main__"`. Otherwise, `__name__` is equals to the name of you python file (whitout extension) or module name.

Comment: Please quote your sources. This is directly taken from the official documentation <https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#idiomatic-usage> While helpful, it's only fair to quote where you got it from.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your script, the `__name__` variable equals `__main__`. When you import a script,`__name__` will contain the name of the script.

One important reason to add `if __name__ == '__main__':` to you script is to make sure that this code is not executed when your script is imported from another script. Because in that case the `__name__` will be the name of your script.

See this answer for more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/6914378

So when you run `test_employee.py`:

- `__name__` in test_employee.py will be `__main__`
- `__name__` in employee.py will be `employee`
- `__name__` in unittest.py will be `unittest`

For more information you can have a look here:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/whats-in-a-python-s-name-506262fe61e8/

Comment: I'm asking in a general question, explain the `__name__` and `__main__` , forget the test employee and these, it's something like a general question and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Functions and classes that are defined, but none of their code runs. When You Use **name** == **main** its Executed when invoked directly as when its invoked directly **name** will be main.

Answer (score 0):

You are running the test inside main module..not the Employee(which is being imported)..so when you setUp the unittest, the instance of Employee becomes the instant of TestEmployee class..Hope it was clear to you!!!

Comment: Well, can you tell me an example of running the test in a non-main module to help me understand?

Comment: what defines the main program?

Answer (score 0):

The `__name__` and `__main__` has been very well described in below Python documentation:

[https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#:~:text=%C2%B6,entry%20point%20to%20the%20application](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#:%7E:text=%C2%B6,entry%20point%20to%20the%20application).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32787065)

Comment: That's a Good point. Thanks @rtoijala